# Alinear Input (Botón) dentro de Row en boostrap

Tags: mvc, cshtml

Estoy intentando alinear un botón dentro de un  clase "row" igual que hago con el resto de campos y no lo consigo. Creo que el problema puede ser que el botón no tiene el texto fuera de el (el "tag" que lo identifica quiero decir), por tanto, esa distancia no la toma en cuenta para alinear. ¿Cómo puedo alinear el botón con el resto de campos? Me gustaría encontrar una forma haciendo uso de las clases que proporciona boostrap en vez de mediante css, si es que se puede, claro...

Pongo como ejemplo una imagen y el código .cshtml

[image: Imagen de muestra (Botón "create" a alinear con Tag3 y 4)]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="Tag3" class="control-label">Tag 3</label>
        <input asp-for="Tag3" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Tag3" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="Tag4" class="control-label">Tag 4</label>
        <input asp-for="Tag4" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Tag4" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control-static col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias, un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero que te sirva aún. Debe haber una forma mejor de hacer pero una manera es esta

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre">
   </div>  
<div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
  <label for="importe">Importe</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="importe">
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-1 offset-md-1">
  <label for="importe">&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" class="form-control" id="importe" value="Aceptar">


  </div> 

<div class="form-group col-md-1 ml-auto">
  <label for="importe">&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-" class="form-control" id="importe" value="Cancelar">
</div>
```